# How do I use the 3 minute playback feature?

Tags: recording, shadowplay

I just got an awesome clip of pushing my friend off of the Iron Keep Bridge in Dark Souls 2 with the Bone Fist (Probably too late now, but will be remembered). I remembered the 3 minute feature with ShadowPlay, which my GeForce GTX 660 Ti is compatible with. Is there a way to enable it and what is the default save location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is the "Shadow" mode of ShadowPlay.

To activate it, you'll need to open the *ShadowPlay* window by clicking on the *ShadowPlay* button in the top right corner of the *GeForce Experience* window, then clicking on the *Mode* button, and finally selecting either *Shadow & Manual* or *Shadow*.

To use it, you merely need to press the required keyboard shortcut, which you can easily set for yourself under "*Save the last n minutes recorded*". You can choose any value from 1 to 20 for `n` by clicking on the *Shadow time* button next to the *Mode* button. The required option is under `Preferences > ShadowPlay > Keyboard shortcuts`.

Shadow recordings are saved in the same place as regular recordings which can be configured as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude! Now next time I get a Battlefield Hardline Beta Sniper Rifle kill from 500 meters in a moving helicopter headshot on the pilot with the zoom on 200 meters, it will be captured. :D (God that did happen to me, and when I realized it wasn't recorded... At least my friend there remembered it)

Comment: @mugen2099. Remember you can set the recording length up to 20 minutes. I'm not sure where exactly ShadowPlay puts the not-yet-saved shadow recording (probably under *Temporary files location*), but if you've got the RAM and HDD/SSD to spare, recording 20 minutes might be better and safer than just 3. Good luck getting another such kill ;)